# How to redirect /post-name to /post/post-name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a wordpress web site. I want to redirect my /post-name urls to /post/post-name. When I tried this code, It'll end infinite redirect. I searched at google but I couldn't find anything. How can I redirect my /post-name urls to /post/post-name ?

Thanks...

RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ /post/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)(/?)$ /en/post/$1/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I found the answer of my own question :)
This code is working.

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/$ http://websiteurl/post/$1